# How can I set password in aws EC2 instead of ppk file?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created a account in aws ec2 and logged in through converted ppk file with putty. Now I would like to login via password.

Here how can I set password?

Can any one provide step by step process.

Thanks in advance.

Please help!!

Comment: This may help: https://coderwall.com/p/j5nk9w/access-ec2-linux-box-over-ssh-without-pem-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about logging into an instance via a SSH password?

If so, know that EC2 instances only allow key-based SSH authentication by default.

In-order to do ssh password authentication, edit the configuration file(as for Debian linux),

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

Edit following to change it to yes,

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Restart ssh service,

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Then try SSH into instance,

```
ssh <username>@<IP address or public DNS>
```

Comment: Hi vineeth thanks . Please also let me know how can I setup new password for login?

Comment: Its just linux user management thing. Once you configure SSH password authentication as above, it can use the user password to authenticate against SSH.

Change password using ,

**passwd <username>**

You might need an existing user password. In the case of EC2 default users, (ubuntu for a case), change to root user and change password without considering the existing password.

Change to root using,

**sudo -i**

or 

**sudo su**

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable Password authentication in SSH by editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
   --> change PasswordAuthentication no to PasswordAuthentication yes
2. Restart SSH Service
   --> service sshd restart
3. Set a Strong password and open up a new terminal and access the instance with username and password.
   --> passwd username

Comment: Thank you . Got everything 

Comment: And I have one more doubt. I got a ip address by aws ec2 account by default.

Is it possible to change the IP address ?

Pls help..

Comment: Which IP address you are referring to? Is it Private IP or Public IP ?

Comment: Public IP address.  

And one common doubt how can I change stack overflow username to my original name through app or website..

Comment: Create a new Elastic IP and Associate it to your Instance. Once you associate new EIP to the instance, the existing public IP will be released. Please be aware that AWS charges for EIP if it is not associated with any running Instance.

Comment: And to update your Profile, follow below steps.

Click on your name in the top right, Click on the tab "Edit Profile & Settings", Edit "Display name" field
and Complete your profile.